# How to get every character in a string that comes before any integer?

Tags: python, regex

If I had a string that looked like this:

```
hello my name is12345 blah blah things
```

and another one that looked like this:

```
slim shady4321 oooh la la
```

How would I grab only the characters that come before the integers?

Is the best way to loop through all of the characters in the string and check whether the character is an integer and then break from the loop?

Comment: What about `\D+(?=\d)`? Gets `hello my name is` and `slim shady`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following regex:

```
^\D*
```

Explanation:

`^`: Start symbol (make sure the match is from beginning of string)
`\D*`:Sequence of characters that are non-digits.

(**Assuming** that in your examples you only want to retrieve `hello my name is` and `slim shady`).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to solve your problem (while using search pattern from user ctwheels)

```
import re

pattern = '\D+(?=\d)'

string1 = 'hello my name is12345 blah blah things'
string2 = 'slim shady4321 oooh la la'

match = re.search(pattern, string1)
match.group(0)
```

will return

`'hello my name is'`

Comment: OP specified *integer**s*** (with an s), which makes me believe that they're trying to match before `12345` and not only `5`. Also, *characters* usually references any character unless explicitly announced as *word characters* or similar

Comment: yea, that's true, adjusted to your search pattern

Answer (score 0):

I would go for simplicity:

```
s = "hello my name is12345 blah foo432423 blah things"

words = s.split(' ')

for word in words:
    if not word.isalpha():
        print(word.rstrip('0123456789'))
```

This splits your string into words and check every single one if it contains only letters. If not (what we are looking for), we take that word and remove trailing numbers. Gives you:

```
is
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use positive look ahead. Match all non-digit characters before a digit.

```
\D*(?=\d)
```

Comment: Why do you copy previous answer? Where is the added value?

Comment: They were 15 minutes apart so my page hadn't refreshed. In any case they are not the same answer as mine will include empty strings @Toto

Answer (score 0):

No regex, no imports, just simple built in class.

```
s = 'hello my name is12345 blah blah things'
ss = 'slim shady4321 oooh la la'
w = ''
for c in ss:                                 # OR use the below
    if str(c).isalpha() or str(c).isspace(): # if not str(c).isdigit():
        w += c
    else:
        break;

print(w)
```

output:

```
hello my name is
slim shady
```